# C++ CreateProcess fails when triggered from Task Scheduler

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks, createprocess

I have a C++ program which uses CreateProcess. This works fine when I manually trigger the application. However, when the application is triggered from the task scheduler it returns met the error code 6, what does this error-code refer to?

On the net I can't find any message corresponding to the error code?

The code I use:

```
int StartCommand(char* Command) {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    bool CommandStatus = CreateProcess(NULL, Command, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW | CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    AssignProcessToJobObject(FilerHandle, pi.hProcess); // Does not work if without CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB
    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    if (CommandStatus) {
        return pi.dwProcessId;
        }
    cout << GetLastError() << endl; //RETURNS ME 6
    Message = "Couldn't start command!";
    Exit(Message);
    return 0;
    }
```

***Note that when I trigger it manually, the same command get's executed successfully***

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx - Found by searching for win32 error codes.  Impossible to tell which line set it though, probably CloseHandle() which makes it useless.  You need to check all return values for errors and call GetLastError() immediately after the failing call for it to be useful.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, Why is this different with manual and automatic triggering?

Comment: I don't know.  I don't know what your whole program looks like or what command you're trying to execute.  Perhaps your path to the file is wrong. Perhaps it requires permissions that aren't available. That's what error checking and debugging is for, to determine the why.

Comment: Tesk Manager runs your program with no working directory and possibly without environment variables.  It can even run it as a different user that has different permissions (e.g. local account).  We need to see what the task scheduler settings are and which line in your program generates the error code.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, great. The working directory is indeed true I had to add the working directory manually to make other errors go away. I will try to get some better error handling. I will come back soon

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, after the bool CommandStatus line it returns me the error code 5. Oh wauw that seems like an access denied? I will try to schedule the task to start under the current user

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, schtasks run under the current user by default? So how can it not have permissions starting from task scheduler? Triggering manually works, which should have the same permissions? (just validated, it runs under the authentication of the account which I also use to trigger it manually)